# How to structure Xtext grammar to aid parser recovery

Tags: parsing, grammar, xtext

I have had an issue with my Xtext grammar in that the parser cannot recover upon reaching a misspelled keyword. Here is a minimal grammar which reproduces the issue and resembles my actual grammar structure:

```
Model:
    'NS' name=ID
    (
        a+=TypeA |
        b+=TypeB |
        c+=TypeC
    )*
    'EndNS'
;

TypeA:
    'TypeA' name=ID ';'
;

TypeB:
    'TypeB' name=ID 

    'EndTypeB'
;

TypeC:
    'TypeC' name=ID

    'EndTypeC'
;
```

So if I created a file with the following text:

```
NS myNamespace
    TypeA myA;

    TypeB myB
    EndTypeB

    TypeC myC
    EndTypeC
EndNS
```

And then I misspelled the `TypeA` keyword, then both the `TypeB` and `TypeC` entries would also fail to parse despite having a keyword centric grammar. (This problem will still occur if you remove the namespace concept, or if you make the type entries ordered) My expectation is that the `TypeA` entry would be null, but upon reaching the `TypeB` keyword, the parser would recover and add them to the AST.

My question then is, is there an issue I am missing in my current grammar and how can I structure this grammar to provide the best parser recovery ability?

Comment: Are you sure Xtext/Antlr supports such feature ? Personally I don't recall seeing this type of parser recovery. I'd even go as far as saying that even in Java you have that issue.

Comment: I would say Java does, I think the equivalent would be like having multiple methods but if you mistyped public then all of your other methods below would fail to parse as well, I only see this type of behavior in most languages with unclosed strings and multi comment lines. There is a blog from one of the xtext guys on it [here](https://zarnekow.blogspot.com/2012/11/xtext-corner-7-parser-error-recovery.html)

Comment: From playing with an Xtext-based DSL I have at hand where the syntax is similar to your "TypeA x;", it sounds like it is able to recover if you forget the ";". But it does not recover from misspelling the first keyword, or from adding some garbage after the ";", so I guess error recovery is actually quite limited.

Comment: Yes it seems that way, I was hoping there was just something I was missing